# How does TSQL determine how to apply the + operator?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Sample code:

```
declare @str nvarchar(100)
set @str = 5
set @str =  @str + 2
select @str
```

Above code sets `@str` to '7'. But the plus sign can also be used for concatenating strings (e.g. if that were to happen, then `str` would be '52' at the end).

My question is, how does SQL Server determine whether the `+` should be a string concat, or an arithmetic plus operation in cases like above?

Comment: Don't store raw numbers into a `varchar` type.

Comment: yes, i'm aware. was just curious.

Comment: If the two values for the `+` are of different type, the type with the higher precedence "wins" - here, since `int` has a higher precedence than `varchar`, SQL Server will convert both values to `int` and thus perform an arithmetic sum. If both values were `varchar`, then a string concatenation is performed. See the [official MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) about type precedence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two values for the `+` are of different type, the type with the higher precedence "wins".

Here in your case, since `int` has a higher precedence than `varchar`, SQL Server will try to convert both values to `int` and then perform an arithmetic sum (which works in your case, since your "string" is also a valid `int` value).

If both values were `varchar`, then a string concatenation is performed. See the [official MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) for more details about type precedence